# Determinant of an operator with no eigenvalues is positive. Not sure where my proof went wrong.

Tags: linear-algebra

In my class, I was given the following:

"Let $A$ be an $n$ x $n$ matrix with real entries and define the operator $T$ : $\Bbb{C}^n$ $->$ $\Bbb{C}^n$ by declaring that its matrix for the standard basis of $\Bbb{C}^n$ is $A$. 
If $T$ has no eigenvalues in $\Bbb{R}$, then $\det$($A$) > $0$."

I was able to find that the $\det$($A$) $\ne$ $0$ using the characteristic polynomial, but then noticed something interesting. If $q(z)$ is the characteristic polynomial, I can write:

$\det(zI-T)$ = $z^n-tr(T)*z^{n-1}+...+(-1)^n*\det(T)$

Because both sides are equal to $q(T)$. Setting $z = 0$ the LHS yields:

$\det(-T) = \det(-I*T) = \det(-I)*\det(T) = -\det(T)$

So I have:

$-\det(T) = (-1)^n*\det(T)$

Which shows that $n = \dim(V)$ must be odd. Using the Intermediate Value Theorem, this shows that T must have a real eigenvalue.

If anybody could give me any insight into where my logic is flawed it would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: $\mathrm{det}(-I_n) = (-1)^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that $\det(cA)=c^n\,\det A$.

For completeness, let me add an argument that shows that $\det A>0$. Since $A$ is real with no real eigenvalues, all roots of the characteristic polynomial appear together with their conjugate. Thus, the eigenvalues of $A$ will be 
$$
\lambda_1,\overline{\lambda_1},\lambda_2,\overline{\lambda_2},\ldots,\lambda_r,\overline{\lambda_r}.
$$
Then
$$
\det A=\lambda_1\overline{\lambda_1}\lambda_2\overline{\lambda_2}\cdots\lambda_r\overline{\lambda_r}=|\lambda_1|^2\,|\lambda_2|^2\,\cdots\,|\lambda_r|^2>0.
$$

Comment: Of course, thank you! I have no clue how I could have made such a stupid mistake.

Comment: Been there, done that. Several times :)